# ms-access custom menubars and registry

Tags: ms-access, registry

I was performing one of these saturday morning tasks, trying to understand why searching my computer registry for some piece of information will either take a loooooot of time or even force me to stop the process. Using one of these registry cleaners, I discovered that the code was spending tens of minutes looping through lines looking like:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Access\Settings\CommandBars\ACBCustom Popup...
```

As I was not able to access these lines through my standard regedit (it was freezing ...), I found a piece of code [here](http://blog.mvct.com/technology/remove-custom-menu-bars-from-microsoft-access-2003/) that I slightly updated to be able to count all these lines to finally discover that I had 70 797 ACBCustom Popup lines in my registry!

I imagine (but I am not sure ...) that it has something to do with the extensive use we are making of custom menu bars in our access apps, where each form has its specific menubars created at runtime, but I thought these commandbars were automatically deleted at the end of the process. If so, what are these lines in the registry for? How can we avoid their creation while running an ms-access app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

As nobody seems to know (or to care), I did my homework. This is just to confirm that a line is added in the registry each time the `Application.CommandBars.Add` method is used.

Unless you explicitely delete all temporary commandbars before closing your access app, these lines will be kept in the registry in a permanent way.

I guess having these commandbars deleted before closing the app can then be considered as a 'best practice'. A solution would be to explicitely delete temporary commandbars once they are not needed anymore. Another option is to browse all commandbars, deleting the temporary ones, when quiting the application:

```
For i = Application.CommandBars.Count To 1 Step -1
    If not Application.CommandBars(i).BuiltIn Then
        Application.CommandBars(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```